# mysqldump vs innodb hot-backup

Tags: backup, innodb, mysql

I need to perform a backup of entire innodb-database into local file with possibility to restore data from it. Currently I use MySQL Community Edition, but it doesn’t have innodb hot-backup features.

So I’m wondering, which negative aspects should I expect using mysqldump for hotbackup instead of innodb hot-backup features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-backup.html

I think that the mysqldump is locking each table during the dump process. There should be no limitation in restoring the data, because you will get the data as SQL files